# Include a cover page then title page in book class

Tags: titles, covers, fullpage

I am attempting to place a cover on a document that I am typesetting.  I have a coverpage as a png file and wanted to place that as a full page first, then have the second page with the other information like title etc.  I am not able to get the correct output.  I am getting the image with the title text on the first page.  Can you assist me in having first the cover page with just the image, and then the 2nd page with the tiles?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(-8,0){\includegraphics[scale=1]{cover}}} % Image background

\newpage

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
{\LARGE\bfseries My thesis title}

\vspace{1cm}

{\Large Some subtitle for my thesis}

\vspace{2cm}

{\large An Author}

\vspace{2cm}

{\bfseries Submitted in fulfillment of the degree \ldots}

\vfill

{\itshape University of Randomville}
\end{titlepage}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it seems that you need to include something in your cover page to be finished and start a new page which will include the titlepage. Try adding `\mbox{}` between `\AddToShipoutPicture*` command and `\newpage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code between `\begin{document}` and first `\newpage` contains no non discardable element. Therefore a page is not created and background figure appears on the first real page which is due to `titlepage` environment.

Please read [egreg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) excellent answer to [Why \newpage needs at least \null to create a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289535/why-newpage-needs-at-least-null-to-create-a-page) to understand it better and also to find the solution:
insert `\vspace*{0pt}` before first `\newpage` to have a real cover.