# Why \newpage needs at least \null to create a page?

Tags: page-breaking

Trying to answer to [Include a cover page then title page in book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289347/include-a-cover-page-then-title-page-in-book-class#comment700147_289347) I've found that `\newpage` only creates a new page if there is some contents, i.e.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

doesn't produce any result (no pdf file) while

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\null\newpage
\end{document}
```

does it (empty page with 1 on footer). Instead of `\null`, `\mbox{}` also works.
Could you explain why?

My understanding is that an empty page is not empty because LaTeX automatically introduces headers and footers. I was using `\pagestyle{empty}` or `\thispagestyle{empty}` could understand it, but first code doesn't fit this case.

Comment: Very informal idea: Well, to create a new page `\newpage` you need at least one page, otherwise you can not go to the next one. So, a page must contain at least an empty char.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Headers and footers are added *after* TeX has decided it wants to do a page break, so the fact that they are empty or not is completely irrelevant.

A page must have something non discardable in it (a box, a rule, a whatsit), because discardable items (glue, penalties, kerns) are discarded at a page break.

So doing `\newpage\newpage` does not produce a blank page because, when issued in vertical mode, it essentially does

```
\vfil
\penalty-10000
```

Note that the start of a document is implicitly considered as a page break, so initial discardable items are indeed discarded. That's the same reason why you get no vertical space when you do

```
\begin{document}
\vspace{10cm}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

and “Hello world” will appear at the top.

The macro `\null` does `\hbox{}`, so it provides a box. A better method for adding something invisible is doing

```
\vspace*{0pt}
```

There's a *very* good reason for this: after the final `\clearpage` (that implicitly calls `\newpage`) issued by `\end{document}`, TeX is still doing its work and it's ready to make a new page, because pending floats might remain. If its behavior was changed to allow `\newpage` making a page without non discardable items, you'd *always* get a blank page at the end.

---

This is the full definition of `\newpage`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 6503 (2015/10/01 patch level 2)
\def \newpage {%
  \if@noskipsec
    \ifx \@nodocument\relax
      \leavevmode
      \global \@noskipsecfalse
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@inlabel
    \leavevmode
    \global \@inlabelfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak \@nobreakfalse \everypar{}\fi
  \par
  \vfil
  \penalty -\@M}
```

This opens the problem of where `\if@noskipsec` is true; well, it is at startup, but it is set to false at `\begin{document}` and back to true when a run-in section title is being typeset. The command `\@nodocument` is responsible of issuing an error message if some text is typeset before `\begin{document}`, but is later set to be equivalent to `\relax`. So the purpose of the first conditional is to put things into order when something like `\paragraph{Title}\newpage` is found.

The conditional `\if@inlabel` is true when LaTeX is processing an `\item`, so that part is for recovering from input such as `\item\newpage`. Finally `\if@nobreak` is true when LaTeX has typeset a “block” sectional title (`\section`, for instance) and, again, this is for recovering from something like `\section{Title}\newpage`.

So the initial part is just code that tries to avoid later problems in presence of disputable code. If none of those (hopefully) rare situations occurs, then just `\par\vfil\penalty-10000` is issued. Note that `\par` is normally implicit in `\vfil`, but just in case the user has redefined `\vfil`, it is issued nonetheless.

I don't recommend `\leavevmode\newpage` that still appears to work; the command *does* start a paragraph, contributing `\parskip` glue and `\baselineskip` glue too. To the contrary, `\null` or `\vspace*{0pt}` just contribute a box/rule of zero height and depth (the latter also a 10000 penalty and zero glue), with no `\parskip` and `\baselineskip` glue.

Not a big deal, actually, since we're analyzing the problem of making an apparently empty page: a blank box, an invisible rule or a blank paragraph don't make such a big difference, but the less we contribute the better. Starting a paragraph also frees the contents of `\everypar`, which can have some side effect in some situations.

Comment: +1. Could you explain why `\vspace*{0pt}` is better?

Comment: @Sigur Because it's documented in the manual and `\null` isn't.

Comment: I'd have issued `\leavevmode\newpage`.

Comment: @A.Ellett `\leavevmode` isn't a documented latex command either and the behaviour of  `\leavevmode\newpage` is _much_ more complicated to analyse (and less desirable) than either null or vspace* (I'll leave that to egreg:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So that opens a question for me:  what does "documented LaTeX command" mean?  Since, after all, I can find `\leavevmode` in `source2e` but I can't find `\vspace*{0pt}` in `source2e`.  Where should I be looking for such documentation?

Comment: @A.Ellett Lamport's latex book for example is the standard latex reference. `\vspace*` is of course in source2e, that's where it is defined.... `\DeclareRobustCommand\vspace{\@ifstar\@vspacer\@vspace}`

Comment: @A.Ellett I added some motivation for not using `\leavevmode\newpage`

Comment: having done the set task, you get a vote:-)